# What does "Wealth formation" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I googled them but I couldn't find any good answers.

“**Wealth formation** in Asia is very strong,” DBS CEO Piyush Gupta said May 2 after his bank’s results. “If you are one of the top 10 players in the market, you will get **a degree of growth** just by being in the market.”

Source: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-05-09/wealth-investments-paying-off-for-singapore-s-three-big-banks

Comment: **wealth formation**  is economics jargon and usually refers to the accumulation of wealth,  by nations, social classes, or even families. A lay person's synonyms for this term might be **prosperity** or **affluence**.   The rise in the number of affluent people in Asia has led to the banks  growing their wealth-management businesses.  More people have more money and banks are capitalizing on this fact by offering those people ways to grow their money through investment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wealth formation** in this context refers to the collection and acquisition of financial assets. By saying that wealth formation in Asia is very strong, Gupta is saying that Asia's banking and commerce companies are attaining and retaining strong financial assets (strong meaning likely to raise in value).

With regards to what he means by the **degree of growth** comment, he's saying that the Asian financial market is doing so well overall that as a big player, even if your company is not doing anything, the value of your company is likely to grow because investors and traders are interested in the current potential of the market.